# Preventing users who are dbo from dropping their own databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

We allow our users to be `dbo` in their own databases, however this does give them the ability to drop their own databases. This doesn't happen very often, but I want to prevent them from doing this.

I've devised the following trigger that prevents this happening and it restricts the dropping of databases to `sysadmin` role members:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [deny_customer_db_drop]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR DROP_database
AS
IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin') = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'You are not permitted to drop this database'
    ROLLBACK
END
GO
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this using permissions without tweaking each login's own specific permissions?

Comment: Since it does not happen very often, I would say the trigger is sufficient.

Comment: @ShawnMelton - possibly, but I have to spend time trawling the background trace logs pinpointing when they did and then proving it was their finger trouble. It's one less thing I want to have to do.

Comment: Why not just have it raise an error, and roll the transaction back. Then you could also just write to a audit table, then you don't have to traverse the trace files.

Comment: What do you have to change? Are all of your db owners also sysadmin?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - no, they are just dbo in their own database.

Comment: So if you use the trigger, why would you have to do anything else with logins or the logs? You could always have the trigger send you an e-mail.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - using a trigger didn't seem very elegant. I just wondered if the security infrastructure in SQL Server could enforce this instead. But if you folks think this is the optimal approach then I'm happy.

Answer (score 4):

That is your only option.

As a side note, you may also want to check for server role db_creator = 0 as well.